# Find node name based on its inner text

Tags: c#, xml

Given an `XML` file and a unique `InnerText` value, I need to find the `Name` of the node. I **can't assume anything on the nesting of the node**, because the structure of the xml file might change. How can I do it as fast as possible (in `C#`)? for example, if the InnerText I'm looking for is "**seven**" and the xml file looks something like:

```
<blue>
    <red>
        <orange>one</orange>
        <pink>two</pink>
    </red>
    <yellow>
        <black>
            <purple>three</purple>
            <green>
                <grey>seven</grey>  
            </green>
        </black>
    </yellow>
</blue>
```

I want to return the value "**grey**". I worry about complexity because the file can be really big, so I can't (and don't need to, since I don't need all the values) read it all.

Comment: How big is "really big"? If you *can* read it all in one go, this is basically a single line of LINQ to XML...

Comment: If you can't load the whole XML in one go, then ignore the fact it's XML and treat it as a simple search task. Open the stream, search for ">seven</" then read the text up to ">" to get the node name.

Comment: See following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387013.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396